# how to display data from join table to a view in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I tried to join 2 tables there are tables product and purchase order here are the tables :

1. Tables Product (tb_produk)
   [tb_produk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy8Yu.png)
2. Tables purchase order(tb_pocust)
   [tb_pocust](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvwac.png)

I want to display the calculation of qty_po based on name of the product, in phpmyadmin I try the sql like this :

`` SELECT tb_produk.nama_produk,SUM(`qty_po`) AS TOTAL FROM tb_pocust JOIN tb_produk ON tb_pocust.id_produk = tb_produk.id_produk GROUP BY tb_produk.nama_produk ``

then it went like what I expect it, here's the result of the sql :
[tables join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Tcxu.png)

but when I try to display on view in codeigniter it goes error like this:
[view table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eInJ9.png)

I don't have no idea why the qty_po column is could be undefined? here's also the view code:

```
    <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h5 class="judulpr">Pilih Periode</h5>
            </div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-6">Bulan</label>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <input type="text" name="bulan" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <table class="table" border="1">
            <thead class="table-dark">
                <tr>
                    <td>NO</td>
                    <td>Nama Produk</td>
                    <td>Qty Total</td>
                    <td>Aksi</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
                    <?php 
                    $no = 1;
                    foreach ($rekap as $pr): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <?php echo $no++ ?> </td>
                            <td> <?php echo $pr->nama_produk ?> </td>
                            <td> <?php echo $pr->qty_po ?> </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
        </table>
</div>
```

and here also the controller :

```
        {
            $data['rekap'] = $this->m_marketing->rekap();
            $this->load->view('halaman/marketing/lap_rekap',$data);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try $pr->TOTAL? since that is what your query says.